# Chrome appdata makes logging in on terminal server slow

Tags: windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop, thin-client

I have a virtualized Windows Server 2008 R2 with Remote desktop services installed. Users can connect to this server with their own credentials.

However, the longer the users use their account the bigger it gets. I've found out that the appdata of Google Chrome can take more then 1GB, that's more than 75% of the total user profile size.

Users have to use Chrome, but is there any way possible so it will use up less space? Or that the appdata folder just gets excluded?

Comment: What exactly is your question.  It sounds like Chrome is doing what its suppose to do and creating a cache.

Comment: alright, how can i prevent chrome from building a cache or not include the cache in the transfer of the profile.

Comment: I would just use a [extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) to do that or use DevTools  You can also use [Incognito](http://superuser.com/questions/334793/how-to-disable-browser-cache-in-chrome) mode.