# How long until an old website visitor sees new web design?

Tags: browser, html, web, browser-cache

Given that there are no cache settings in the HTML page, how long until an old website visitor see a new website design without force refresh?

Comment: *"no cache settings in the HTML page"* does not imply that the server might not set headers...

Comment: Have you changed the DNS settings for the website? If so they can take up to 48 hours to change.

Comment: If new webdesign has new "names" of files; it should be immediately after first visit. Read this few paragraphs https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting so it all depends on website designer (coder). Is this a example of HTML cache settings?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### How long before a website visitor sees a new website design without force refresh?

> Assumption: There are no cache settings in the HTML page

It depends on the browser cache settings.

Note:

- The browser settings described below can be temporarily overridden using the appropriate "Refresh" or "Forced Refresh" commands.

---

#### IE

There are four options under Check for newer versions of stored pages:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> - **Every visit to the page**:
>
>   When you return to a page you viewed previously, Internet Explorer
>     should check to see whether the page changed since you last viewed it.
>     If the page has changed, Internet Explorer displays the new page and
>     stores it in the Temporary Internet Files. Note that selecting this
>     option can slow down browsing between pages you have already viewed.
> - **Every time you start Internet Explorer:**
>
>   When you view a Web site that you have visited before in the same
>     Internet Explorer session, Internet Explorer uses the cached temporary
>     Internet files instead of downloading the page. If you press F5 or
>     click Refresh, Internet Explorer downloads the page.
> - **Automatically (Internet Explorer 5 and later only)**:
>
>   This is the same as the previous setting, but with a logic algorithm
>     to understand the habits of Web page behavior. This setting specifies
>     that when you return to a page you viewed previously, Internet
>     Explorer should not check to see whether the page has changed since
>     you last viewed it.
>
>   If you select this setting, Internet Explorer checks for new content
>     only when you return to a page that you viewed in an earlier session
>     of Internet Explorer or on an earlier day. Over time, if Internet
>     Explorer determines that images on the page are changing infrequently,
>     it checks for newer images even less frequently.
> - **Never**:
>
>   Internet Explorer does not check the Web server for newer content.

Source [How Internet Explorer cache settings affect Web browsing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263070)

---

#### Mozilla

```
Netscape (all versions since 6.0)
Mozilla Suite (all versions)
Phoenix (all versions)
Firebird (all versions)
Firefox (all versions)
Thunderbird (all versions)
Minimo (all versions)
SeaMonkey (all versions)
```

The preference `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` controls this:

> - `0`
>
>   Check for a new version of a page once per session (a session starts
>     when the first application window opens and ends when the last
>     application window closes).
> - `1`
>
>   Check for a new version every time a page is loaded.
> - `2`
>
>   Never check for a new version - always load the page from cache.
> - `3`
>
>   Check for a new version when the page is out of date. (Default)

Source [Browser.cache.check doc frequency](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency)

---

#### Chrome

Chrome caches pages unless it has been told not to.

To disable the cache see [How to disable browser cache in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/334793/how-to-disable-browser-cache-in-chrome)

---

#### What does "out of date" mean, where does it get the date reference?

> Browsers will usually get this information through HTTP headers sent
>   with the page.
>
> For example, the Last-Modified header tells the browser how old the
>   page is. A browser can send a simple HEAD request to the page to get
>   the last-modified value. If it's newer than what the browser has in
>   cache, then the browser can reload it.

Source [How does the browser know a web page has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862752/3536342), answer by [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65295/seth)

---

#### Further Reading

- Optimizing content efficiency: [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

Comment: Worth mentioning other factors may be caching the site as well. If it happens to be a relatively popular site, your ISP may cache the pages. If you are behind a decent router or on a corporate network, the site may get cached automatically as well.